# Old projects won't render on a newly installed Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, ide

I recently reformatted my computer and when I reinstalled Android Studio and its packages and tried to run my previous projects it said it can't render properly.

What should I do to resolve this?

Also, the file structure doesn't show on the left hand side of Android Studio.

[image: Actual Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by importing the old projects to android studio.